# regex expression for 12 hr time format

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regex expression in javascript for 12 hr time format , which is as :

```
12:00 am - 12:00 pm
```

I am able to write the regular expression for `12:00 pm` or `12:00 am` , but when expression for "-" is included , it fails.

Comment: Please provide sample input, your expected output and what you have tried so that other people can help you out.

Comment: var TotalshiftVal = "01:00 am";console.log( (/(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\s)(am|pm)/).test(TotalshiftVal))

Comment: I need to write regex for 12:00 am - 12:00 pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(1[012]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9](?:\s)(am|pm)\s*-\s*(1[012]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9](?:\s)(am|pm)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/28

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
regex="/(0[0-9]|1[012]):([0-5][0-9])\s?am\s?-\s?(0[0-9]|1[012]):([0-5][0-9])\s?pm/"
```

**[This is a demo](http://regex101.com/r/wY7uK9/1)**

It gives you a regex for a : `HH:mm am - HH:mm pm`.